# Best way to handle reactive list storing data within Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a Shiny app which is based on some imported data (via `inputFile()`). Such data is later handled as a **list** of data frames, such as: `db <- list(df1, df2)`.

I was wondering what is the best way to handle such data in a reactive context.

On one hand, I do not want to use `reactiveValues()` (i.e. `rv$db$df1 or $df2`) because, if a modification is performed on a child element (`df1` or `df2`) all reactive components on `df1` and `df2` (such as observers) will be triggered.

On another hand, `reactiveVal()` is, from my understanding, used for storing a single value.

What Shiny reactive tool should we use to store such a `db`?

Comment: I'd suggest to assign each `data.frame` directly to a `reactiveValues()` object resulting in e.g. `rv$df1`. You can use `reactiveValuesToList()` to get back to the previous format.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't want to some specific assignment as there are plenty of other information stored within `db` such as other df or meta data (I just mention 2 df above as an example).

Comment: Than your requirements are mutually exclusive. Either you have specific assignment and reactivity specific to these objects or you have a single object (list) which will trigger reactivity once it's altered.

Comment: btw. you can use `do.call` to do the assignment. you don't have to do it by hand - e.g.: `rv <- do.call(shiny::reactiveValues, somelist)`. Please see [this](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2511)